# Set multiple column values based on changing column conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I want to take a dataframe of levels with different importance ranging from FIRST - THIRD like:

```
    FIRST    SECOND    THIRD
0   Yes      Yes       Yes
1   Yes      No        No
2   No       Yes       Yes
3   No       No        Yes
```

And say that if FIRST is the highest level, and FIRST = Yes, then set the remaining columns to No. This logic should extend down the chain i.e If FIRST = No, but SECOND = YES, then THIRD should = NO.

In essence it should only keep the "Yes" in the highest valued column. In my real dataframe the No is simply an empty string "".

Example output:

```
    FIRST    SECOND    THIRD
0   Yes      No        No
1   Yes      No        No     #Stays the same
2   No       Yes       No
3   No       No        Yes    #Stays the same
```

I have Implemented it with nested for loops, but thats obviously not ideal with anything Pandas.
I'm sure there is a more elegant vectorised solution, can anyone please help me out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comapre by `Yes` and for first `Yes` use double [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html), then compare by `1` and create new `DataFrame` with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = df.eq('Yes').cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=1).eq(1)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(mask, 'Yes','No'), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df)
  FIRST SECOND THIRD
0   Yes     No    No
1   Yes     No    No
2    No    Yes    No
3    No     No   Yes
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way that I can extend this to show the first 3 "Yes" (for another similar problem), I tried changing eq(1->3) but not working 100%, can you please elaborate on the use of the functions in the statement.

Comment: @liamod - Not sure if undertand, can you post new question?